# Java Databinding: how to display data in a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, data-binding, jtable

I'm a .net developer that would like to try develop some simple apps in Java. I would like to know how to do databinding in Java.

How can I show a query result in a `JTable`?

Comment: you can check here http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: Then (after reading GustlyWind suggestion), you should definitly take a look a GlazedLists library (http://www.glazedlists.com/), that will help a lot in JTable usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GustlyWind's comment is the best place to look on how to use a `JTable`.  The key for the data is getting the items in a model.  You can use the `DefaultTableModel` which would require that your table results are put into a 2D Array or Vector.  Or you could implement your own model that uses other custom objects from your application or a different underlying data structure.

Either way, as you loop through the `ResultSet` of your query you are going to have to pull the relevant data and stick it in some sort of `Collection`.

Comment: So, in Java don't exists a mechanism like .net databinding. Something like: mytable.datasource = myds ; mytable.datamember = my-table-name ?

Comment: Not that familiar with .net databinding, there might be a third party library that could do that, but it looks scary.

Comment: In my experience (indirect only, I have supervised a team using it), .NET data-binding is a nightmare for applications with a complex UI, it almost always leads to spaghetti code that nobody can maintain.